# Multipart Image Alamofire 4 swift 3

Tags: swift, image, upload, alamofire, multipart

I've a big problem when I try to update an image to my Db.

I must to upload an image, and some string value.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageCropped = selectedImage
            self.sendImageWithMultipart()
            imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
        }
    }

func sendImageWithMultipart() {        
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {
            multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append("\(HGYGjihf746fg743g)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"auth_token")
            multipartFormData.append("\(0)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"os")
            multipartFormData.append("\(10.0.3)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"os_version")
            multipartFormData.append("\(3.0.3)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"app_version")

            if let photo = self.imageCropped, let jpegImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 50.0) {
                print(jpegImage)
                multipartFormData.append(jpegImage, withName: "profile_photo", mimeType: "image/*")
            }
        }, to: "\(Constants.GENERAL_ADDRESS_2)\(Constants.API_MODIFYUSER_PROFILE_PHOTO)", method:.post, headers:["Content-Type":"multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__"], encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(request: let upload, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):
                upload.validate().responseJSON {
                    response in
                    if response.result.isFailure {
                        debugPrint(response)
                    } else {
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                NSLog((encodingError as NSError).localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
```

but the result is this:

```
[Request]: "\(Constants.GENERAL_ADDRESS_2)\(Constants.API_MODIFYUSER_PROFILE_PHOTO)"
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17023c0e0> { URL: "\(Constants.GENERAL_ADDRESS_2)\(Constants.API_MODIFYUSER_PROFILE_PHOTO)" } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, private";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 5545;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 10 Nov 2016 10:49:00 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.18 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.1k-fips PHP/5.6.21";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.21";
} }
[Data]: 5545 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(500))
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 500467740.667, "Initial Response Time": 500467740.793, "Request Completed Time": 500467743.733, "Serialization Completed Time": 500467743.733, "Latency": 0.126 secs, "Request Duration": 3.066 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 3.066 secs
```

the problem is how I convert the Image, or the Content type or what?

thank you

Comment: how about explicitly specifying the mime type: `multipartFormData.append(jpegImage, withName: "profile_photo.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")`

Comment: have you been able to resolve?

Comment: I was not able to solve the problem. And I've also tried specifying the mimetype, but nothing

Answer (score 0):

This may potentially resolve your issue:

```
let endpoint = "https://api.blah/images/" + id + "/documents"

let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(type.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"type")
                multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }, to: endpoint, method:.post, headers:headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(request: let upload, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):
                upload.validate().responseJSON { (response) in
                    if response.result.isFailure {
                        debugPrint(response)
                    } else {
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                NSLog((encodingError as NSError).localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

Seems to reach my server, but in my case, I get a 400 back (probably failing tv4 validation).

Comment: Most of this looks like an answer, but if you have a related question, please ask that as a new question. Question material mostly won't be seen here, and material that is clearly a question is usually deleted by a moderator.

Comment: but i must to use the image?not the image's URL?